# Choose relation one to many or many to one for design

Tags: relation

I need help to define the relationship between the models.

**I have 2 models :**

1. User
2. Product

The user own many products and the product is owned by only one user.

**My use case :** 
The logged user can access to some information in his personnal account : 
- Display all his products
- Add a new product

Later i'd like to add use case like : any user can see any product in some screen (and know product's owner).

So, i can define the models like that :

**A) ONE TO MANY**

```
class User{

private Set<Product> products;
..
}

class Product{

...
}
```

**B) MANY TO ONE**

```
class User{

 ..
}

class Product{

 private User owner;
}
```

**Which is the best ? one to many or many to one ?**

Because my use case display the product of logged user Im thinking its better to choose **one to many**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely option for this would be One To Many as a User owns products. He has products (so a list of them). In the second option you would say: a product owns a user.

As for the requirements:

- Display all his products

  - Will you display all his products or will you display all products that have the user as owner.
- Add a new product

  - The user adds a product to his list compared to a product adds the user as an owner.

The last requirement is quite tricky: "any user can see any product in some screen (and know product's owner)". Now if this is the main functionality the second design would be better as it would be easier finding the owner from a product. Though the use case description seems to be quite focussed on the One to Many design.

Comment: I will start with one to many because its the main functionality by now, later i will add a reference to the user (from the class Product), thanks !